# AWS: Creating Persistent AMI

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have setup create an AMI from a EBS-backed [Official Ubuntu Image](http://cloud.ubuntu.com/ami/) to running a web server.

I have follow the guide below carefully from the link below.

http://www.elastician.com/2009/12/creating-ebs-backed-ami-from-s3-backed.html

http://jimmyg.org/blog/2007/amazon-ec2-for-people-who-prefer-debian-and-python-over-fedora-and-java.html

After successfully of registering the AMI, an AMI identifier will be shown.

I tried start the new AMI, but all the setting (Apache, Django, Data, etc) are not in the new AMI itself. Anyone know how can I creating a persistent AMI?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install these before registering the new AMI?  I'm not clear on what you're expecting.  Fortunately, as it is EBS backed, you can install what you need and simply stop the instance, rather than terminate it.  Still, if you didn't install the software before registering the AMI, then that software won't be in the AMI and won't be there when you launch an instance.

Comment: Yeah, I did the install before I register the new AMI. Still the data is loss when I start the new AMI

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from EC2-API. It's possible via AWS Management Console, specially when you have EBS backed image.

1. Log into `AWS Management console > EC2 tab > Instances`
2. select the instance that you have all your software installed.
3. click `Instance Action`, select `Create Image (EBS AMI)`.

wait, and see the new AMI is ready under `AMI` menu. You can instatiate it, it will have your software.

*Beware*: certain directories like `/tmp, /mnt` and some more are not included in AMI.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not the Amazon account administrator. I am only able to access through Access ID and Secret key

Comment: the first link that you have given worked fine for me earlier. However, I had a S3 backed AMI to convert to EBS. I usually prefer Management Console, but if you do not have an access, you could probably try [this tutorial](http://webkist.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/creating-an-amazon-ec2-ebs-ami-from-a-running-instance/).

Comment: The syntax looks different. I tried on a Ubuntu AMI half way but are stucks @ the MAKEDEV.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a weak answer but I just used the AWS web interface at http://aws.amazon.com/console/. I create EBS-backed AMI's all the time and new instances from them, containing all the software I installed from the cloned instance with no problem.

Instance storage is a little more tricky, but it looks like you're using EBS anyways.